# Grub error: no such partition after fresh install

Tags: system-installation, grub2

I just installed Scientific Linux 6.5 from DVD. The installation went smoothly and finished. But after booting it complains:

```
error: no such partition 
Grub rescue>
```

Prior to this computer, I tried the DVDs on another and the installation worked nicely and there was no such error. Both systems have a Windows 7 installation also.

Comment: Here is what I would do: Reinstall, and make sure the entire Linux system is on a single partition (no fancy LVM stuff), perhaps with a modest swap partition.  Simplifying the partition table may (or may not) resolve the issue.

Comment: What is in your /etc/fstab and what is when you type blkid? Sorry, but I don't have on my keyboard key simmilar to '.

Comment: It would be helpful to see the grub configuration

Comment: In my configuration, I have only set the root (/) and home (/home) partitions.

Comment: @UUV: I am not too familiar with grub, how can I view the grub configuration?